# Angular Optional Hash Url Parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm trying to make a dynamic hash Url so i can book mark it so angular routing will pick it up. I have over 50 search fields that could be appended to the hash.  Is there a way to create a generic route that captures all the optional hash values using $routeParams instead of having to specify every single search parameter?

I'm using $location.path(path, false) to inject my new url with the hash so the screen doesnt refresh, but angular routing picks it up.

Sample Url(s)

**#/search/a/1/b/4/c/0**

**#/search/c/111/d/2/e/0**

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/search/a/:a?/b/:b?/c/:c?/', {
        templateUrl: '/app/partials/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    }).
```

Comment: I'm not quite following the `?` in your url since you have multiples...  are you meaning the pattern could match `/search/a/a1?qp1=abc` **and** `/search/x/x1/y/y2/z/z3?qp1=abc&qp2=123`.  Something like that?  So you don't really know how many actual levels of your path you may have before the query parameters?

Comment: I'm just trying to pass X number of parameters and have the route provider pick it up without refreshing the page. So that's why i used $location.path(path, false).  I didnt know if this could be done with a single path or not.  The code can be ignored since it was a guess. If i'm doing it completely wrong thats fine, im just looking for how to do it.

Comment: I forgot to mention i need the url to change in the browser but not refresh.

Comment: $routeProvider.
    when('/properties:path?', {
        templateUrl: '/app/partials/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    }).
If i use, it will change my url, and then my $routeparams with have a property path that is the query string.

Comment: And I take it this last thing you commented on is undesirable correct?

Comment: I dont have enough angular experience to say if it is a good way or not.

Answer (score 0):

#### query params

Even after exchanging comments with you, I'm not entirely sure what your end-goal is regarding the URL.  I think with the dynamic nature of your *params* you'd probably fair better by using traditional query params for a single state.

```
'/search?{param1}{param2}{param3}....{param50}'
```

That assumes that you could have any number of combinations of parameters that may or may not be related to one another.

#### borrowing from a RESTful approach

This assumes that you're not happy with the query param approach and indeed are seeking a more stateful way of doing this.  It's a tad more *RESTful* looking assumes that you have a set number of parameters per *resource position* (meaning "/position1/pos2/pos3").  In other words, you are not going to have all and any possible combinations but a set number **reasonable** set of combinations.

```
'/search/make/{make_id:apple|windows|android}/model/{model_id:ipad|iphone|win_phone|galaxy|nexus}/style/{style_id:mini|nano|giant}'
```

***note** - I am borrowing from the way ui.router defines URL parameters, with the assumption that the non-ui.router router handles the regexp similarly.*